# How to: for loop minimum value dictionary python?

Tags: python, for-loop, min, unpack

I have a problem with creating a tuple with a minimum value from a dictionary. I found a way with the lambda function but my teacher says that I need to create a for loop where i "unpack" the dictionary, find the minimum value of the dictionary, and return it.

I'm lost, this is what I have now but I need to change the fastest_travel_mode(distance):

```
travel_times = {"Walk": (2, 5, 0),
                "Bike": (4, 18, 3),
                "Bus": (8, 35, 8)}


def travel_time_per_mode(distance):
    fastest_times = {}
    for mode in travel_times:
        setup_time, speed, finish_time = travel_times[mode]
        fastest_times[mode] = setup_time + 60 / speed * distance + finish_time
    return fastest_times


def fastest_travel_mode(distance):
    travel_time = travel_time_per_mode(distance)
    for fastest_mode in sorted(travel_time.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]):
        return fastest_mode


def main():
    distance = float(input("How many kilometers do you have to travel? "))
    print("When you have to travel", distance, "km, taking a", fastest_travel_mode(distance)[0], "will be the quickest way to your destination with an approximate time of", int(fastest_travel_mode(distance)[1]), "minutes.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried:

```
def fastest_travel_mode(distance):
    travel_time = travel_time_per_mode(distance)
    for fastest_mode in sorted(travel_time.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]):
        return fastest_mode
```

It works but i need to do it another way including the steps creating a for loop "unpack" the dictionary, find the minimum value of the dictionary, and return it.

Comment: You don't need to use `sorted()`, use `min()`.

Comment: *"I have a problem with creating a **tuple** with a minimum value from a dictionary"*. Do you expect a tuple or a single value?

Comment: Sorry, this is all new for me. fastest_travel_mode(distance) should return a tuple indicating the quickest mode of travel and the total travel time. So for example ("Walk", 8.0) when the distance is 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min` method. By default it searches minimum by looking at `dict` keys, but you can provide `key` argument to search by something else. In that case we use `get` function which tells *find the key with minimum value*

```
def fastest_travel_mode(distance):
    travel_time = travel_time_per_mode(distance)
    mode = min(travel_time, key=travel_time.get)
    return mode, travel_time[mode]
```

And now you do the calculation twice, you can do it once and store the result:

```
def main():
    distance = float(input("How many kilometers do you have to travel? "))
    mode, time = fastest_travel_mode(distance)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! mode = min(travel_time, key=travel_time.get)
    return mode, travel_time[mode]  Did the job!